# The escape key does not work the same way in all browsers

Tags: javascript, browser, escaping, keycode

With the following code I can scroll back and forth in my picture gallery with the arrow keys. I would like to be able to use Escape to end the display of the images - but this only works in Chrome and Internet Explorer, in Firefox and Edge you also have to press the Shift key.

```
<script>
document.onkeydown = checkKeycode
function checkKeycode(e)
{  var key;
  if (window.event)
  {  key = window.event.keyCode;}
  else if (e)
  {  key = e.which;}
  // Escape 27
  if (key == '27')
  {  window.location.href='<?php echo $_SESSION["reset"] ?>';}
  // UP 38
  if (key == '38')
  {  window.location.href='<?php echo $_SESSION["reset"] ?>';}
  // Left
  if (key == '37')
  {  window.location.href='?index=<?php echo $prev ?>';}
  // Right
  if (key == '39')
  {  window.location.href='?index=<?php echo $next ?>';}
}
</script>
```

Comment: `keyCode` and `which` are deprecated an you shouldn't use them, use `key` instead. Also, you should use `e` instead of `window.event`. If you have this code from a tutorial of some kind, stop reading / watching that tutorial because it has to be 15 years too old.

Comment: As recommended, I "modernized" the code and now it works with all browsers. Many thanks for the tip.